# How to invert two lines and remove the line break between these with sed in bash scripts?

Tags: html, bash, curl, sed

I wrote a bash script to parse an HTML file with curl into a variable. I got code like this:

```
<title>aa bb cc</title>
<time>12345</time>
```

I would like to edit this code to get this result:

```
<time>12345</time><title>aa bb cc</title>
```

I suppose that you can't do it with sed. Anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit better your workflow, so that we can understand why editing the file by hand, as you did here is not enough. Is it because there are many pair of lines? Is it because those two lines are not a file but the ouput of `curl`? Please, clarify.

Comment: It's because of many lines. Yes, these lines are the output of curl.
I could start Emacs and do a search/replace with regular expressions, but it would be nice to let the script do this work.

Comment: Yes, you could have done it with `sed`, [if only you tried](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/); look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005460/5825294).

Answer (score 0):

The following works for the simple case that you presented, however you might want to provide a more general example, if you want to obtain a more effective solution.

```
your_curl_command | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```

What the command above does is joining one line to the current one (`N`) and inverting the two lines while eliminating the newline character from the middle (`s/…/…/`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result="";while IFS= read -r line ;do result=$result$line;done < yourfile.html;echo $result
```

Comment: Why don't you split this thing on more lines? It'd be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the curl through an `awk`.
I simplistic example -

```
var="$( curl "$url" |  
         awk '/title/{title=$0}
              /time/{time=$0}
              END{ printf "%s%s", time, title }' )"
```

That only works if those are the only two lines returned, which seems unlikely, but it should give you something to work from.